# How to achieve offline voice recognition and trigger the keyboard microphone in React Native?

Tags: react-native, offline, keyboard-events, voice-recognition, react-native-voice

I'm currently working on a React Native project where I need to implement voice recognition functionality. I'm using the react-native-voice package for this purpose. However, I've noticed that this package requires an internet connection for voice recognition to work.

Is there a way to achieve offline voice recognition using react-native-voice or any other package in React Native? Additionally, is there a way to trigger the keyboard microphone (like the one used in messaging apps) for voice input in React Native?

Any insights, suggestions, or alternative approaches would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!